# Customise the hover bottom label of bar chart in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, bar-chart, plotly.js

I'm working on a plotly.js bar chart and I wish to customise the text of the second over label that is displayed at the bottom of the bar on hover.

I know how to configure the label text, the ticks text but not this little "second" label which is unfindable in the documentation (or at least I didn't find it).

On this image you can find circled in red this second label I want to format :

[image: In red the thing I want to change]

Comment: Can you please provide some code in the form of a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example